# CMake error during gnuradio installation using PYBOMBS

Tags: cmake, gnuradio

```
bumblebee@JARVIS:~$ sudo pybombs install gr-osmosdr
PyBOMBS - INFO - PyBOMBS Version 2.3.2
PyBOMBS.Packager.apt - INFO - Install python-apt to speed up apt processing.
PyBOMBS.install_manager - INFO - Phase 1: Creating install tree and installing binary packages:
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
The directory '/home/bumblebee/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Install tree:
|
\- gr-osmosdr
   |
   +- airspy
   |
   +- hackrf
   |
   +- gnuradio
   |
   +- bladeRF
   |
   +- gr-iqbal
   |  |
   |  +- libosmo-dsp
   |  |
   |  \- gnuradio
   |
   \- soapysdr
PyBOMBS.install_manager - INFO - Phase 2: Recursively installing source packages to prefix:
PyBOMBS.install_manager - INFO - Installing package: soapysdr
PyBOMBS.Packager.apt - INFO - Install python-apt to speed up apt processing.
Cloning:     (100%) [==========================================================================================================================================================================================================]
PyBOMBS.Packager.apt - INFO - Install python-apt to speed up apt processing.
Configuring: (100%) [==========================================================================================================================================================================================================]
Building:    (100%) [==========================================================================================================================================================================================================]
Installing:  (100%) [==========================================================================================================================================================================================================]
PyBOMBS.install_manager - INFO - Installation successful.
PyBOMBS.install_manager - INFO - Installing package: gnuradio
PyBOMBS.PackageManager - WARNING - A source build for package gnuradio was requested, but binary install was found!
Install gnuradio from source despite binary install available Y/[N]? y
Cloning:     (100%) [==========================================================================================================================================================================================================]
Configuring: (100%) [==========================================================================================================================================================================================================]
PyBOMBS.Packager.source - WARNING - Configuration failed. Re-trying with higher verbosity.
-- Build type set to RelWithDebInfo.
-- Extracting version information from git describe...
-- Compiler Version: cc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
-- Compiler Flags: /usr/bin/cc:::-O2 -g -DNDEBUG  -std=gnu99 -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized
/usr/bin/c++:::-O2 -g -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized
-- ADDING PERF COUNTERS
-- Building Static Libraries: OFF
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   program_options
--   filesystem
--   system
--   regex
--   thread
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.14", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- 
-- Checking for module SWIG
-- Found SWIG version 2.0.12.
-- 
-- The build system will automatically enable all components.
-- Use -DENABLE_DEFAULT=OFF to disable components by default.
-- 
-- Configuring python-support support...
--   Dependency PYTHONLIBS_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency SWIG_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency SWIG_VERSION_CHECK = TRUE
--   Enabling python-support support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_PYTHON=ON/OFF
-- Checking for module 'cppunit'
--   No package 'cppunit' found
-- Could NOT find CPPUNIT (missing:  CPPUNIT_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- 
-- Configuring testing-support support...
--   Dependency CPPUNIT_FOUND = FALSE
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/GrComponent.cmake:75 (message):
  user force-enabled testing-support but configuration checked failed
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:373 (GR_REGISTER_COMPONENT)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/local/src/gnuradio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/usr/local/src/gnuradio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
PyBOMBS.Packager.source - ERROR - Configuration failed after running at least twice.
PyBOMBS.Packager.source - ERROR - Problem occurred while building package gnuradio:
Configuration failed
PyBOMBS.install_manager - ERROR - Error installing package gnuradio. Aborting.
```

Comment: Did you install the dependencies listed for example at [GNURadio UbuntuInstall](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/UbuntuInstall#Install_Dependencies), in particular `libcppunit-dev`?

Comment: Why you do not want to install `gnuradio` and `gr-osmosdr` with `sudo apt-get install gnuradio gr-osmosdr`? This will install `gnuradio` *3.7.9.1-2ubuntu1* and `gr-osmosdr` *0.1.4-8* (on 16.04 - xenial). If you need to build it from source you should use `sudo apt-get build-dep gnuradio gr-osmosdr`.

Comment: I want it for gr-gsm. Gnuradio is failing to import qtgui. Also PyQt4 cannot be imported in python while PyQt5 can be , I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some requirements are missing.

I've experienced this too - sometimes the package managers don't handle these errors very well. However, installing the widest possible dependencies solved this problem for me on Ubuntu 18.04 + Python 2 + PyBOMBS + GNU Radio 3.7:

1. From GNU Radio's [UbuntuInstall](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/UbuntuInstall#Bionic_Beaver_.2818.04.29_through_Eoan_Ermine_.2819.10.29):

   ```
   sudo apt install cmake git g++ libboost-all-dev python-dev python-mako \
   python-numpy python-wxgtk3.0 python-sphinx python-cheetah swig libzmq3-dev \
   libfftw3-dev libgsl-dev libcppunit-dev doxygen libcomedi-dev libqt4-opengl-dev \
   python-qt4 libqwt-dev libsdl1.2-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev python-gtk2 python-lxml \
   pkg-config python-sip-dev
   ```
2. From Ettus Research's [Knowledge Base](https://kb.ettus.com/Building_and_Installing_the_USRP_Open-Source_Toolchain_(UHD_and_GNU_Radio)_on_Linux):

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y install git swig cmake doxygen build-essential libboost-all-dev \
   libtool libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev libudev-dev libncurses5-dev libfftw3-bin \
   libfftw3-dev libfftw3-doc libcppunit-1.14-0 libcppunit-dev libcppunit-doc \
   ncurses-bin cpufrequtils python-numpy python-numpy-doc python-numpy-dbg \
   python-scipy python-docutils qt4-bin-dbg qt4-default qt4-doc libqt4-dev libqt4-dev-bin python-qt4 python-qt4-dbg python-qt4-dev \
   python-qt4-doc python-qt4-doc libqwt6abi1 libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev \
   libfftw3-doc ncurses-bin libncurses5 libncurses5-dev libncurses5-dbg \
   libfontconfig1-dev libxrender-dev libpulse-dev swig g++ automake autoconf \
   libtool python-dev libfftw3-dev libcppunit-dev libboost-all-dev libusb-dev \
   libusb-1.0-0-dev fort77 libsdl1.2-dev python-wxgtk3.0 git libqt4-dev \
   python-numpy ccache python-opengl libgsl-dev python-cheetah python-mako \
   python-lxml doxygen qt4-default qt4-dev-tools libusb-1.0-0-dev \
   libqwtplot3d-qt5-dev pyqt4-dev-tools python-qwt5-qt4 cmake git wget libxi-dev \
   gtk2-engines-pixbuf r-base-dev python-tk liborc-0.4-0 liborc-0.4-dev \
   libasound2-dev python-gtk2 libzmq3-dev libzmq5 python-requests python-sphinx \
   libcomedi-dev python-zmq libqwt-dev libqwt6abi1 python-six libgps-dev libgps23 \
   gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps python-setuptools
   ```

I hope this helps.